# merge two android projects

Tags: android, eclipse

i want to merge two different android projects to use the functionalty of both in one project.
They are using complete different packages for the files.

I copied the files with the different packages in one project, but there is a problem with the manifest file.

Is it possibly to have different packages in the android manifest file?
Or how can i solve this? Maybe specify the activities with the whole package and not use ".shortcut" ?

I hope there is someone to help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Building a library can solve this problem. This is the way I have proceeded on my side for a similar question:

- I had a project `ProjectA` that was finished and working
- I had a new project `ProjectB` that had to reuse some functions of `ProjectA`.
- These functions were likely to be reused again so I built a library `Library1` and I **moved** the necessary code from `ProjectA` to it. I set the `Library1`'s `isLibrary` flag to true under Eclipse (that's in the project properties - let me know whether you would like more details on this and I'll edit that post if needed).
- Then I modified the `ProjectA`'s properties to use `Library1`. This also implied some refactoring on `ProjectA` side but that was OK.
- And finally, I created my `ProjectB` as a client of `Library1` as well. And this was straightforward.

Comment: I assume you are an Eclipse user. If so, you just need to flag it as a library in Eclipse: right-click your project and go to 'properties', then select 'Android', and check the 'is library' box at the bottom of the dialog window. Even though it is a library, your project needs an `AndroidManifest` file. It can be minimalistic: the `<manifest>` and the `<uses-sdk>` elements are sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to merge multiple projects into one. However, you can choose to build one of the projects as a library and import it into the other.

See [working with library projects](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html#libraryProject)

Answer (score 1):

you can merge the code if it not having large scope..ie not having Native library and etc...
for merging the project you need to refactor package name, layout xml and etc...
for example. main.xml are seperate for both of package so need to care of such things