# Merge two Android projects in Eclipse (without using library)

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine

I have two projects of Android.

p1. Notepad project(Big project)

p2. Sync-Android( its an appengine connected Android project)

(p2 is a sample project provided by Google Plugin and hence very small in size.)

I wanted to merge both of them, I read some posts here on StackExchange. And copied all the source files from p1 NOtepad sample project to Sync-Android and I also merged res folder of both.( I will take care of main.xml and string.xml, p2 is a small project so not a problem.)
But I get the problem of R class of android.  This may be because the xml files were not built and didnt insert values in gen>R.java. That is the code that i copied have error like.

> R.string.button_dont_save

its showing error. Is there any way dealing with that...

PS:-I have read [merge two android projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240047/merge-two-android-projects) and the easy solution is making library of one project. I cannot make a library for a specific reason and so I have to merge both the projects.

Summarry:- If I can resolve the error of Resource class i.e

> R.string.button_dont_save, R.style.Theme_Notepad etc.

I think i will be able to handle it.

Thanks

Comment: Not quit understand the error "R.string.button_dont_save" you attached, What is the actual problem of your R class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that resource or the string is missing in resources/strings.xml. Check the existence of the resources and strings. If you are merging two projects, then you should not replace the resources. you should append the ones resources to other to the same file name. If you properly do this, then it should work. try cleaning the project and re-building it.